# Can not use a comment display mode

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, comments

In my comment type, I created a "teaser" view.

When I enable the debug mode in the "service.yml" file, the display modes of the comments do not appear in the suggestions.

Why ?

How to use a different display mode than the default one ?

How to customize the display mode "teaser" with a twig file ?

[image]

I created a file named `comment--field-article-commentaire--teaser.html.twig`

It contains the following code, but it is not rendered

```
<article{{ attributes.addClass('js-comment comment--field-article-commentaire--teaser') }}>

  test comment

</article>
```

I also created the following file `comment--field-article-commentaire.html.twig`

It contains the following code. It works, but impossible to use "teaser"

```
<article{{ attributes.addClass('js-comment comment--field-article-commentaire') }}>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 bs-region-comment">

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 bs-left">
      {{ drupal_entity('user', comment.uid.target_id, 'comment') }}

      <div class="bs-field-status">
       {{ drupal_entity('user', comment.uid.target_id, 'status') }}
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 bs-right">
     <b><i>{{ created }}</i></b>
     {{ content.field_article_commentaire }}
     {{ content.links }}
     {{ content.flag_report_comment }}
    </div>

  </div>

</article>
```

**UPDATE**

I found this :

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions

```
Pattern: comment--[comment-field-name]--[node-type].html.twig
Base template: comment.html.twig (base location: core/modules/comment/template/comment.html.twig)
```

There is no explanation for displaying a display mode. However, it is possible to add display modes to the type of comment.

How to use them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ drupal_entity('comment', content.comment_body['#object'].id, 'teaser') }}`

should do the trick.